# Code.EarthEngine: Uploading multiple images, ingestion failed - time out

Tags: google-earth-engine

As part of my project I am importing rasterized surfaces into GEE which later on I am using in conjunction with other raster images (involving satellite climatic images etc) to produce spatial surfaces.

The images I am trying to upload contain estimates obtained from geostatistical modeling and are stored into GeoTiff rasterbricks. Each brick contains 200 layers (samples per px) with a total size for the entire brick approximately 900mb each rasterbrick.

If I upload the files and wait for 100% ingestion one at a time then everything works fine, however if I wish to upload simultaneously then most of the task fail - time out.

I realize that the sheer volume can be an issue on its own, however I was wondering if there is anything else that could be done from my side as a user to circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use command line utilities for this. You can put your data first in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) and then move them to asset. Here is my workflow for uploading large amount of raster:

- Create a Storage Bucket following https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets
- Upload image files to this bucket using https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects
- Once the files are in GCS bucket, use earthengine command line
  tools to upload image files from GCS bucket to earthengine asset: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line (see upload section)

Also check the tutorial from GEE team: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials#importing-and-exporting

It will take you some time and effort to set up the authentication for GCS and GEE command line tools. There might be some cost associated with using GCS. Note that GCS provides 5GB free storage per month.

Comment: Thanks a lot for going through all the information! Really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Because i spend a lot of time to get it working here some details for linux users:

### Get [Google Cloud Software Development Kit (SDK)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux)

```
#Unzip:

tar -xvf file you downloaded  

# Install the gcsdk                                                                                              
./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh          

 # Refresh environment                                                                                              
. ~/.bashrc
```

### [Installation of google-api-python-client and earthengine-api](https://www.tucson.ars.ag.gov/notebooks/uploading_data_2_gee.html#)

```
# ******************** Command Line Instructions ******************************#
# Installing Google API-Python-client library
sudo pip install google-api-python-client

# Ensure crypto library is available. No error is expected after running the following:
python -c "from oauth2client import crypt"

# If no error, continue with the Installation of Earth Engine Python API

sudo pip install earthengine-api

# Switch the expanded directory and run script
cd earthengine-api-VERSION
python setup.py install

# Authenticate into GEE from terminal. The following line should show a URL 
# that you can paste into a browser window to authenticate with your account
# that has access to GEE.
python -c "import ee; ee.Initialize()"
```

### [Authentication to Google Cloud](https://www.tucson.ars.ag.gov/notebooks/uploading_data_2_gee.html#)

Once you have succesfully authenticate you dont have to do it again

```
# ******************** Command Line Instructions ******************************#
# This command will try either to open a browser or display a link that you can
# paste into browser window.
gcloud auth login

# Set project ID as created at https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/
gcloud config set project xxxx-yyyy-172116

# Create a bucket, a folder for data staging
gsutil mb gs://my_bucket

# list buckets you have in your project
gsutil ls gs://
```

### Upload files from local drive to your bucket

```
gsutil -m cp *.tif gs://my_bucket/
```

### Then you can create a folder in earth engine and a collection

```
earthengine create folder users/yourusername/folder
earthengine create collection users/yourusername/folder/collection
```

### [Use a bash script provided by this tutorial to upload files with and without properties](https://www.tucson.ars.ag.gov/notebooks/uploading_data_2_gee.html#)

Answer (score 0):

Is the gcloud availble yet? When I try `gcloud auth login` it is not recognized as package. I have the Google API installed.